# VueJS: é possível saber qual foi o último objeto alterado?

Tags: vue.js

Estou com seguinte problema, preciso da funcionalidade de "voltar" em um botão, se eu estiver no paso2 ao clicar eu volto para o paso1 e do paso3 para o paso2, é possível pegar o último objeto dentro do **data** que foi alterado?

A minha idéia era ao clicar no botão, pegar o último valor alterado e alterá-lo para **true**.

```
data: {
        paso1: false,
        paso2: false,
        paso3: true
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Basta escutar os elementos com `watch`, ao perceber que o valor foi alterado, é possível mudar novamente para true, exemplo...

```js
new Vue({
      el : "#app",
      data : {
        paso1: false,
        paso2: false,
        paso3: false
      },
      methods : {
        altVal (item) {
          this[item] = 'teste';
        }
      },
      watch : {
        paso1() {
          console.log('valor alterado para : ' + this.paso1);
          this.paso1 = true;
        },
        paso2() {
          console.log('valor alterado para : ' + this.paso2);
          this.paso2 = true;
        },
        paso3() {
          console.log('valor alterado para : ' + this.paso3);
          this.paso3 = true;
        },
      }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.9/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <div id="app">
      <input type="button" @click="altVal('paso1')" value="paso1">
      <input type="button" @click="altVal('paso2')" value="paso3">
      <input type="button" @click="altVal('paso3')" value="paso2"><br>
      {{paso1}}<br>
      {{paso2}}<br>
      {{paso3}}<br>
    </div>
```

Comment: o problema é que eu preciso clicar em um botão só e verificar somente qual foi o último item alterado, independente se ele é o passo 1,2 ou 3

Comment: Seria melhor você explicar o que deseja fazer, pois pode ter uma solução mais adequada, afinal cada vez que for fazer alguma alteração a mesma irá apontar ao objeto data.